# VB6 Frame Height

Tags: vb6, height, frames

I am building a form in which every control except the scrollbars are contained in a frame. The scrollbars, naturally, move the frame.

My form's height x width is 12150 x 15800.
The frame - WHICH IS ENTIRELY CONTAINED WITHIN THE FRAME - is 18935 x 15285.

Despite the fact that I can see the entire frame within the form's borders, it insists that it is 6785 twips TALLER. The width makes sense, however - it is reasonable to say it's 515 twips narrower left-to-right.

What is going on here?

Comment: Please confirm if you're using VB6 or VB.NET, and if VB.NET which version? Also what is the "Frame" you speak of? This is not a standard VB6 nor WinForms control.

Comment: Oops! My bad. I'm using VB6. Frame is a standard VB6 control; however it was replace by Panel and GroupBox in VB 2005 and later, IIRC.

I've been playing around with it, and the form seems to be reporting its size about 1/3 smaller than the objects on it (frame1.Height = 15000 approximately fills form1.Height=10000).

Comment: Assuming all `ScaleModes` are set to `vbTwips`, it could be the Windows DPI support lieing to your application. Does it work any better when the system is set to "100%" font size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `ScaleHeight` is the culprit in this. If you double the ScaleHeight of the form, then all controls' within the form Height will double too, while the Form's height remains the same. Hence the control within the form may have height of lets say 10000 and the Form = 5000

Comment: +1. OP may have inadvertently set a custom `ScaleMode` in the form. A custom coordinate system in which the y coordinates are approximately half-twips and the x-coordinates real twips. This is easily done: if you type in the `ScaleHeight` property, VB6 kindly decides that you *really* meant to create a custom coordinate system in your form

Comment: YES! Thanks! ScaleMode was set to 0-User. When I changed it to 1-Twips, the vertical and horizontal sizes on controls began agreeing with the form V&H sizes.

Must have clicked that at some point in the past, inadvertently.